# Difference between useState and useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I use useState instead of useEffect and it works fine for displaying data (why?)

React.useState(() =>getMovies(), [])

Note : I added console.log and I get same results

Comment: Please *carefully* read the documentation for each: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html and https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html. It's not hard to understand.

Answer (score 2):

When a function is passed to `useState`, this is signaling to React to use [lazy initialization](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#lazy-initial-state) - the function will be invoked to calculate the initial value only when the component mounts.

If the value to be put into state can be calculated/retrieved *synchronously*, this is probably the best design pattern to use - it's short and doesn't require you to later differentiate between whether the state value is undefined or populated.

```
const [stateValue, setStateValue] = useState(calculateExpensiveInitialStateValue);
```

The time to use `useEffect` is when the value to be populated *can't* be computed synchronously, in which case the best approach is to have both `useState` (for the state) and `useEffect` (to indicate that you want to run a function to retrieve the state value just once).

While you theoretically can have a line just like

```
React.useState(() =>getMovies(), [])
```

it's pretty confusing, because

- The resulting state value returned isn't used
- `useState` doesn't accept a second argument dependency array

`useEffect` is more suited for the task because it doesn't have a return value (unlike `useState`), and is more flexible, because it does accept a dependency array. `useEffect` much more clearly indicates to readers of the code "This callback should run only when the dependency array changes."